# Web Scraping with c# and HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

[Screenshot of the code and error message+variable values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSfdJ.png) So, the goal is to  take a word and get the part of speech of the word from its google definition.

I've tried a few different approaches but I'm getting a null reference error every time. Is my code failing to access the webpage? Is it a firewall issue, a logic issue, an {insert-issue-here} problem? I really wish i had a vague idea of what is wrong.

Thanks for your time.

Addendum: I've tried  "**//*[@id=\"source - luna\"]//div***"   and   "**//[@id=\"source - luna\"]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSfdJ.png)**" as XPath values.

```html
//attempt 1////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            var term = "Hello";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=" + term);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string final_response = stream.ReadToEnd();

            MessageBox.Show(final_response); //doesn't execute

//attempt 2////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            var url = "https://www.google.co.za/search?q=define+position";
            var content = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url);
            var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(content);
     //doc is null at runtime
            HtmlNode ourNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"uid_0\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/i/span");
            if (ourNode != null)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(ourNode.InnerText);
            }
            else
                richTextBox1.AppendText("null");

//attempt 3////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = webGet.Load("https://www.google.co.za/search?q=define+position");
     //doc is null at runtime
            HtmlNode ourNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"uid_0\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/i/span");
            if (ourNode != null)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(ourNode.InnerText);
            }
            else
                richTextBox1.AppendText("null");

//attempt 4////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
string Url = "http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/halo-spartan-assault";
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
     //doc is null at runtime
            string metascore = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"main\"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/a/span[1]")[0].InnerText;
            string userscore = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"main\"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a/span[1]")[0].InnerText;
            string summary = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"main\"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li/span[2]/span/span[1]")[0].InnerText;
            richTextBox1.AppendText(metascore + " " + userscore + " " + summary);

//attempt 5////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
             HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
             HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument html = web.Load("https://www.google.co.za/search?q=define+position");
     //html is null
             var div = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"uid_0\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/i/span");
             richTextBox1.AppendText(Convert.ToString(div));
```

Comment: You can use some Dictionary API instead of scrapping webpages, see https://www.wordsapi.com/

Comment: Re: Attempt 2, I don't think it's possible for `doc` to be null there. A constructor always returns an object if it doesn't throw an exception before that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm busy reinventing the wheel here. The value of doc after its created is consistently {HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument} for all the above attempts, except for attempt 1, so its not necessarily null but null reference is the exception thrown

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null because your XPATHs aren't correct or it couldn't find any node based on those XPATHs. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Hung Cao thank you for your response, yes it seems my XPATHs were incorrect. It's working now.:) for some reason, I can obtain the innertext of elements from websites like dictionary.com, thesaurus.com and wikipedia, but not from Google pages... if i wanted to grab the text of the wikipedia excerpt, that comes at the top of a google search, for instance, it doesn't return anything.